RWE: use of target trial emulation framework: why aiming to emulate RCT?
Hernán and Robins [1] introduced the target trial emulation framework in 2016 to define the question of interest in observational studies. The target trial framework asks the investigator to specify key elements of the protocol of the RCT that would ideally be run to address the question of interest. But what if it is impossible to simulate the target RCT, then the causal question can’t be formulated. And why are they aiming to emulate exactly RCT? Is it because in RCT less assumptions are required to define the causal question?
[1] Hernán, M. A., and Robins, J. M. (2016), “Using Big Data to Emulate a
Target Trial When a Randomized Trial Is Not Available,” American
Journal of Epidemiology, 183, 758–764.

+1 that's a fun little paper! I had the same questions where I first read it!

The whole idea of emulating an RCT is because they are generally considered the gold standard for causal inference. (Yes, there is the conversation about meta-analysis of RCTs too, but let's not go there) In that sense, you are correct that with an RCT "less assumptions are required to define the causal question", that is because we expect to have no confounding (i.e. no back-door paths), no unintentional mediation effects and a proper temporal ordering (i.e. no front-door paths).
Now, regarding the point about the impossibility of simulating the target RCT: I think there should be made a distinction between what the paper refers at as the "ideal RCT" and the "target RCT". The ideal RCT is our perfect standard for causal inference, which is likely unattainable. The target RCT serves as a realistic and feasible approximation, guided by the limitations of available data, practical challenges, ethics, etc. The paper itself acknowledge that the ideal RCT is usually unattainable ("we will rarely be able to emulate the ideal trial in which we are most interested"). Its key point is to identify the compromises needed to the target RCT and then to actively work around them. The paper still assumes a counterfactual framework but wants to define the application of it within the bounds of the available data. In practical terms, a target trial is always feasible but the suitability of it as an approximation to the ideal trial is the crux of the matter.
